# Sql удаление строки

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Удаляю строку так:

```
use test_2;
DELETE FROM test_2 WHERE Id=1;
```

но вылезает ошибка

```
0   12  00:03:57    DELETE FROM test_2 WHERE Id=1   
   Error Code: 1146. Table 'test_2.test_2' doesn't exist    0.000 sec
```

в чем ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что в базе `test_2` нет таблицы `test_2`.

Answer (score 0):

Означает, что не существует таблица `test_2.test_2`.
Возможно таблица уже была удалена или не создана.